# Is there any api by which i can login (OpenId) in my web application using windows live Id credential

Tags: c#, asp.net, hotmail, windows-live

Hi I want login to my webapplication using windows live ID credential, is there any api or dll available for this?

Comment: Do you want to enable your proxys

Answer (score 0):

See the links

[Windows live ID authentication](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/08/17/integrate-windows-live-id-authentication-into-your-website.aspx)

[Getting client ID for web authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676626.aspx)

[Using Open ID in asp.net mvc application](http://www.dotnetage.com/publishing/home/2011/04/16/6850/integrating-openid-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-using-dotnetopenauth.html)

Comment: windows live id Oauth not accepting localhost url, how to test it?

Comment: See the live connect link for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Windows Live Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh243650.aspx) and the [Live Connect Developers Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx).  Microsoft's API has changed several times for Windows Live ID, but this is the most current API.